# looking for maps techniques

Tags: c++, c++11, count, stdmap

Here's the code i have working on.it gets the word count from a string but now i have been trying to apply the same logic using maps but couldn't do so since maps can't take key value at run time.how can i store each word in a key from a string in a different keys each time so that i can get actual word count .Any idea how can i do that ?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<string>


 using namespace std;

 int main()
{

    map<string, int> stringCounts;
    map<string, int>::iterator iter;
    string words;


    int TOTAL = 0;
    char a[1000];
    cout << "enter the string = ";
    cin.getline(a, 1000);
    int Totalwords = 0;
    int no = 0;

    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((int(a[i]) >= 65 && int(a[i]) <= 90) || (int(a[i]) >= 97 && int(a[i]) <= 122))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Totalwords++;
        }
        no = i;
    }

    TOTAL = Totalwords;
    cout << "number of words = " << TOTAL << endl;
    string *words = new string[TOTAL];


    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < TOTAL, i <= no;)
    {
        if ((int(a[i]) >= 65 && int(a[i]) <= 90) || (int(a[i]) >= 97 && int(a[i]) <= 122))
        {
            words[j] = words[j] + a[i];
            stringCounts[words[j]]++;
       for (iter = stringCounts.begin(); iter != stringCounts.end(); iter++)
      {
        cout << "word: " << iter->first << ", count: " << iter->second << 
        endl;
      }
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _maps can't take key value at run time_? You can add and change elements in a map at runtime...

Comment: how can i create a key value that would store each word and keeps it count for every iteration ? i mean e.g how would a key would be a key will be created and would store first word of the sentence and in the next iteration a new key will be created and it would store next word in it ?

Comment: I think you didn't understand very well how maps work. Check [this tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stlmap.html) and also [this site with documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/)

Comment: yes exactly @JeJo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i store each word in a key from a string in a different keys
>   each time so that i can get actual word count .

This can be done as follows. You can even deal with each words of the given sentence/ string(assuming that each words has been separated by a space).

A few things to note:

1. If you work with C++, just stick with C++ std library( `#include<conio.h>` has been used here in your soln)
2. Avoid practicing with `using namespace std;`
3. If you wanna use `std::map<>`, you have to include the header `<map>`

For instance here is a sample test output: https://www.ideone.com/KGua1M
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

 int main()
{
   std::string inputString;
   std::cout << "Enter the string = ";
   std::getline(std::cin, inputString);

   std::map<std::string, int> Map; // word, no. of times
   size_t wordCount = 0;
   size_t letterCount = 0;

   std::stringstream sstr(inputString);
   std::string word;

   while (std::getline(sstr, word, ' '))
   {
       Map[word]++;
       wordCount++;
       letterCount += word.size();
   }

   std::cout << "Total Words: " << wordCount << "\n\n";
   std::cout << "Total letters: " << letterCount << "\n\n";
   std::cout << "Each words count\n\n"  ;

   for(const auto& it: Map)
    std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << " times\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: how can i modify my own program so that i can perform the same functionality ? i tried to do something like i created a map with a string key and int value in 2nd for loop's if statement so that in each iteration my word would get stored in string as a key and  but i don't know how can i keep an integer there that would keep word count here ? at the end i cout the map outside the 2nd for loop that fortunately didn't work